# How can I regression/feature test the inclusion of non-python files in a python package?

Tags: python, testing, tox

I am creating a command line application which includes non-python files such
as yaml config files. I would like to distribute these as part of the python
package and therefore would like to ensure that they are part of the installed
package. I would like to use feature tests for this.

I am having a problem where I run my feature tests against the tox installed
sdist of the package and all the feature tests pass, including those that
require the config files. However when I install the package on to a server I
get errors that it can't find the config files. I think know how to fix these
problems, but what I am specifically asking for is help with testing that these
config files are installed and present etc. when running my feature tests, as
currently this appears to be not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not test their existence directly? Something like

```
whitelist =
    /bin/cat
commands =
    /bin/cat {envsitepackagesdir}/MyPackage/config/config.cfg
```